# Присвоить язык для поисковой выдачи BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Кода не будет, потому что я даже не знаю куда копать, и интернет ничего не подсказал.
Нахожусь за границей и поисковая выдача через вызов в коде вводит местную локализацию, что мне совершенно не нужно. Теоретически надо задать параметр языка или локализации, но как это сделать я не знаю. ПОдскажите а)

Код получения страницы:

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
headers = {"user-agent" : USER_AGENT}
zapros = 'Тест'
url = 'google.ru/search?q=определение+слова+{0}'.format(zapros) # url страницы 
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

Comment: Так параметры нужно для сайта задавать, с помощью которого вы ищете. При чём здесь парсер то? Парсер работает с тем, что вы ему передали, то есть выдачу сайта. А про сайт вы ничего не написали, невозможно ничего тут посоветовать.

Comment: Вы говорите - надо задавать для сайта. Я задам этот вопрос ещё раз - Как это сделать? Сайт гугл. Парсинг тут при том что это и есть задача - запарсить выдачу гугла.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, которым вы обращаетесь к сайту. Мы тут не должны гадать - какая ссылка и т.д. Вы всё должны привести в вопросе.

Comment: url = 'https://google.ru/search?q=определение+слова+{0}'.format(zapros) # url страницы

        r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

Comment: насколько я помню, надо передать на сайт куки в которых будет указана локализация, но я понятия не имею как это сформулировать. 

Сейчас у меня выдача по по этому запросу на немецкой локализации, а мне надо что бы она была на русской.

Comment: Такой запрос даже не выполнится из этого кода. Он у меня лично ругается на отсутствие схемы в `URL`

Comment: Потому что headers определяется отдельно. 

Я просто не понимаю, это должно быть что то буквально элементарное как присвоение куки или установка где то дополнительной переменной. 

Давайте так, вот лично вам надо извлечь из гугла на русском языке словарную сноску Oxford Dictionary которая появляется при вводе запроса на определение. 

И появляется проблема - гугл выдает информацию на другом языке, а поскольку запрос был на русском, но в ответ, если разбирать суп методом soup.gettext(); soup.prettify() - выходит инфа на немецком без этой самой сноски. 

Вы знаете как это решить?

Comment: *UPD*

Добавил в топик код headers и zapros

По идее вся проблема должна решаться дополнительным элементом в 
headers, т.е нужна стрчока что то в духе
LANGUAGE = GetSystemLanguage()
headers = { "user-language" : LANGUAGE }

Но я хз как это правильно описать. Можете помочь пожалуйста?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решалась добавлением в header строчки "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.5"

в итоге получилось вот так:

```
headers = {"user-agent" : USER_AGENT, "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.5"}
```